# Помогите правильно написать echo

Tags: php, echo

Помогите правильно написать echo. Выдает ", когда должно было написать Подробнее/Заказать

```html
echo '<a href="/websites/templates/product-iphone.php?productId='.$product['id'].'<input type="button" value="Подробнее">"</a>';
echo '<a href="/websites/order/order.php?id='.$product['id'].'<input type="button" value="Заказать">"</a>';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `echo '<a href="/websites/templates/product-iphone.php?productId='.$product['id'].'"><input type="button" value="Подробнее"></a>';`

`echo '<a href="/websites/order/order.php?id='.$product['id'].'"><input type="button" value="Заказать"></a>';`

Comment: Спасибо большое)